# Digital data transmission

Tags: voltage

Digital data transmission over computer networks is sending pulses of zero volt and 5 volts, per my understanding, to represent binary values which are then converted to their respective decimal values. Is it possible to send other voltages from source too and have the other end recognize the corresponding values? For example, zero volt for a decimal 0, 1 volt for a decimal 1, 2 volts for a decimal 2 and so on and so forth?

Comment: It is possible but you are limited with distance between computers especially at small voltages because of noise and voltage drops.

Comment: Computer networks don't use 0V and 5V, or to put otherwise, if something uses or has used 0V/5V levels, it likely does not fit in the definition of a "computer network". So other values are used anyway, and also multiple voltages can be used to send multiple bits per one voltage level. But how does this relate to electronics, it's more about telecommunications really.

Comment: Anything not relying on analog signal levels is typically referred to as digital. Including bit-banging GPIO with any voltage levels, UART-based busses, SPI, I2C, CAN, USB, current loops, Morse code, smoke signals...

Answer (score 1):

> Digital data transmission over computer networks is sending pulses of zero volt and 5 volts

Not necessarily. This is the case for simple communication that isn't too fast, doesn't go too far, and doesn't have to contend with too much noise. For example, the digital signals of an Arduino are typically signalled with 0 and 5 V. However, this isn't the only way of sending one bit at at time over wires.
For example, [Differential signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signalling) uses a difference of two voltages rather than a single voltage, but still one raw bit at a time. This is commonly seen in things like HDMI/Displayport, PCIe, DDR RAM buses, and industrial networks using CAN bus or RS485.

More directly to your point about distinguishing more than two values at a time (meaning that you indicate more than one bit at a time) - this is quite common as well, although it is often a bit more intricate than just "zero volt for a decimal 0, 1 volt for a decimal 1, 2 volts for a decimal 2". For the purposes of this discussion, we'll use the term *symbol* to represent one of these numbers that we're sending at a time.

The thing you're asking for about directly is **PAM**, or [Pulse Amplitude Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-amplitude_modulation). The voltage of each symbol/pulse represents its value. For example, a four-level PAM symbol would encode two bits at a time using four voltage values, an eight-level PAM system sends three bits at a time with eight levels, etc.

This has real-world uses: for example it's is used in a number of high-speed protocols, such as modern USB, some video card RAM, some Ethernet standards, etc.

Note that in many cases, PAM is itself differential to get the same noise immunity benefits as simple binary differential signalling - e.g. PAM8 over a differential link has eight possible voltage *differences* sent over a pair of wires, with those eight possible voltage differences representing three bits at a time.

---

**Not strictly connected to your query as written, but still relevant:** Another common approach used in some high-speed networks and wireless comms is to *modulate* the signal, meaning that rather than sending a single voltage to represent a symbol, you send a waveform that has useful properties and represents that symbol. For example, that waveform might have a certain frequency (e.g. WiFi is required to use frequencies around 2.4 GHz, 5 GHz, or 6 GHz depending on the type of network). These methods of modulation also let you send a number of bits at a time, for example:

- [BPSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Binary_phase-shift_keying_(BPSK)), which is very simple and robust but sends one bit at a time, by either sending a sine (which we call the *carrier*) or a negated version of that sine (rather than 0 or 5 volts)
- QPSK sends two bits at a time by phase-shifting the carrier by either 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees:
  [image]
  <sup>Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:QPSK_timing_diagram.png</sup>
- QAM encodes information in *both* the magnitude and phase of the carrier, and can transmit many more bits at a time. For example, modern WiFi systems can represent up to 10 bits (1024 different values) per symbol<sup>1</sup> - not with 1024 different voltages, but with 1024 different sines, one representing each symbol
- OFDM uses some mathematical trickery to send multiple symbols at the same time in a way where they can be distinguished easily using additional mathematical trickery at the receiver.

<sup>1</sup> Or less, if the signal is weak or there's interference. WiFi devices coordinate the choice of modulation with each other to ensure that they can communicate even if conditions are poor.